# InDesign changes document dimensions when exporting to PDF

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export

I've been sent an inDesign document with many pages. Format: A4 landscape. Most of the pages are double (two landscape A4 pages one next to the other) but some are triple (three A4 pages one next to the other).

I don't quite understand why some pages are triple and other double, but my problem is this: when exporting to PDF, all of this disappears and is reduced to one A4 simple page, then another, then another till the end.

Why has the structure of the document been somewhat destroyed when exporting to PDF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default export to PDF is single pages. What you're calling pages are correctly termed "spreads," because they actually consist of multiple pages placed side by side. Most long documents appear in InDesign as a single first page (the cover), two-page spreads (the left and right pages as the reader would see them when printed) and a single page at the end (the back cover).

When planning a foldout, a designer will place three (or more) pages side by side, indicating that they are to be printed that way in the final piece.

To have the PDF show spreads rather than individual pages, change the radio button from Pages to Spreads in the dialog:

[image]